# how to search min and max values in 2D array

Tags: php, arrays

am trying to find out min x and min y values in whole array ,  i tried with min and max function but no success so far

i have xy values of board in 2d array

```
$xydata = array(
  array('x' => 17.0, 'y' => 2.83),
  array('x' => 20.83, 'y' =>  65.37 ),
  array('x' => 17.85,'y' => 3.57 ),
  array('x' => 17.13, 'y' => 41.33 ),
  array('x' => 24.27, 'y' => 53.48 ),
  array('x' => 13.1, 'y' => 16.35),
  array('x' => 13.1, 'y' => 66.855 )
);
```

i want to find corners of board

globally i have min x/y max x/y   which i got through min() and max () functions

what i want is to get min y against min x

like if through $xydata i search with min x which is 13.1 i should get min y 16.35 because the other min x 13.1 y value is 66.855 is higher ....  so any idea how it could be done

Comment: This should be done with a simple `foreach`.

Comment: Iterate through and check x value against temp array. If temp array is more than 1, iterate through it and do the same for y value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample code:

```
$xydata = array(
  array('x' => 17.0, 'y' => 2.83),
  array('x' => 20.83, 'y' =>  65.37 ),
  array('x' => 17.85,'y' => 3.57 ),
  array('x' => 17.13, 'y' => 41.33 ),
  array('x' => 24.27, 'y' => 53.48 ),
  array('x' => 13.1, 'y' => 66.855 ),
  array('x' => 13.1, 'y' => 16.35),
);

$min = $xydata[0];
foreach ($xydata as $d) {
    if ($d['x'] < $min['x'] || ($d['x'] == $min['x'] && $d['y'] < $min['y'])) {
        $min = $d;
    }
}

echo'<pre>',print_r($min),'</pre>';    // TODO
```

Comment: nice :) it works , can you  tweak it for  
( min x   max y  )
 (max x   max y  ) 
 (max x    min y )

Comment: You definitely can do it yourself. By understanding what values to compare.

Comment: ya but i not understand one thing ,  $min = $xydata[0];   how to get $max   is it will be $max = $xydata[length];

Comment: No, this line is just to init your `$min` with some data. For max you still do the same `$max = $xydata[0]`. And check other values in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, best solution is use shorting of array

```
$xydata = array(
  array('x' => 17.0, 'y' => 2.83),
  array('x' => 20.83, 'y' =>  65.37 ),
  array('x' => 17.85,'y' => 3.57 ),
  array('x' => 17.13, 'y' => 41.33 ),
  array('x' => 24.27, 'y' => 53.48 ),
  array('x' => 13.1, 'y' => 16.35),
  array('x' => 13.1, 'y' => 66.855 )
);
$count = 0;
foreach ($xydata as $type) {
    $count++;
}
$count--;

function sortByOrder($a, $b) {
    return $a['x'] - $b['x'];
}

usort($xydata, 'sortByOrder');


echo "min of x => ".$xydata [0]['x'];
echo "max of x => ".$xydata [$count]['x'];


function sortByOrdery($a, $b) {
    return $a['y'] - $b['y'];
}

usort($xydata, 'sortByOrdery');

echo "min of y => ".$xydata [0]['y'];
echo "max of y => ".$xydata [$count]['y'];
```

**[DEMO](https://eval.in/700601)**

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below functions:

```
function array_max($a) {
    foreach ($a as $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $value = array_max($value);
        }
        if (!(isset($max))) {
            $max = $value;
        } else {
            $max = $value > $max ? $value : $max;
        }
    }
    return $max;
}

function array_min($a) {
    foreach ($a as $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $value = array_min($value);
        }
        if (!(isset($min))) {
            $min = $value;
        } else {
            $min = $value < $min ? $value : $min;
        }
    }
    return $min;
}
```

Its work fine for me :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_multisort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) to build a function that will give you all possible pairs of min/max:

```
function getXY(array $xyArray, $x = 'min', $y = 'min')
{
    $xFlag = $x === 'max' ? SORT_DESC : SORT_ASC;
    $yFlag = $y === 'max' ? SORT_DESC : SORT_ASC;

    array_multisort(
        array_column($xyArray, 'x'), $xFlag, 
        array_column($xyArray, 'y'), $yFlag,
        $xyArray
    );

    return array_shift($xyArray);
}
```

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/eccf8930bbe6fc2d5bd8693bded09aa2d9e0aee0).